# Use of USGS GeoRSS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georss

I want to use the GeoRSS from USGS, followed the a) add vector layer b) paste URL: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson
and c) add

But I always get the error: "not a valid source"

I am missing something?
W10 enterprise /64bits + QGIS 3.6.0

Comment: I tried the GeoJSON like in this blog post (https://webgeodatavore.com/add-geojson-content-in-qgis-short-recipes.html) and it's not working, neither the dialog method, nor the PyQGIS way.

Answer (score 1):

It just worked for me (3.6.1) - I went to the add vector dialog selected `Protocol` and pasted in the URL.

[image]

QGis then claims it hasn't worked as a protocol, would I like to try file and when I said yes it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: 3.6.1 on W10, it doesn't work. On which OS do you tried ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 64bits

Comment: I confirm : on Windows 10, it doesn't work, on Ubuntu 18.04, it works on QGIS 3.6.1. For me, it's a QGIS bug on Windows.